# Angular - Scrolling bar error "TypeError: tView is null"

Tags: html, angular, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to make a scroll widget for my array in html file but I get an error:
"ERROR ERROR: Not Caught (in promise): Error type: tView is null". I don't know why it doesn't work. To make scrollbar i use CdkScrollableModule, ScrollDispatcher services.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes, Scroll} from "@angular/router";
import {NewPlanComponent} from "../new-plan/new-plan.component";
import {ManagementComponent} from "../management/management.component";
import {TeachersComponent} from "../management/teachers/teachers.component";
import {RoomsComponent} from "../management/rooms/rooms.component";
import {SubjectsComponent} from "../management/subjects/subjects.component";
import {GroupsApiService, RoomsApiService, SubjectsApiService, TeachersApiService} from "../api.services";
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { TeacherComponent } from '../management/teachers/teacher/teacher.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { RoomComponent } from '../management/rooms/room/room.component';
import { SubjectComponent } from '../management/subjects/subject/subject.component';
import { GroupsComponent } from '../management/groups/groups.component';
import { GroupComponent } from '../management/groups/group/group.component';
import { NewTimetableComponent } from '../new-plan/new-timetable/new-timetable.component';
import {focusCellDirective} from '../shared/focus-cell.directive';
import {focusCellSubjectDirective} from "../shared/focus-cell-subject.directive";
import {ScrollDispatcher} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import {CdkScrollableModule, ScrollingModule} from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";
import {CdkVirtualScrollAppendOnlyExample} from "../scroll-bar/scroll-bar.component";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';

export const router: Routes = [
  { path: 'newplan', component:NewPlanComponent},
  { path: 'management', component:ManagementComponent},
  { path: 'management/teachers', component:TeachersComponent},
  { path: 'management/rooms', component:RoomsComponent},
  { path: 'management/subjects', component:SubjectsComponent},
  { path: 'management/teachers/teacher', component:TeacherComponent},
  { path: 'management/rooms/room', component:RoomComponent},
  { path: 'management/subjects/subject', component:SubjectComponent},
  { path: 'management/groups', component:GroupsComponent},
  { path: 'management/groups/group', component:GroupComponent},
  { path: 'newplan/newtimetable', component:NewTimetableComponent},
  { path: 'newplan/scrollbar', component:CdkVirtualScrollAppendOnlyExample},

];
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ManagementComponent,
    NewPlanComponent,
    TeachersComponent,
    TeacherComponent,
    RoomsComponent,
    RoomComponent,
    SubjectComponent,
    SubjectsComponent,
    GroupsComponent,
    GroupComponent,
    NewTimetableComponent,
    focusCellDirective,
    focusCellSubjectDirective,
    CdkVirtualScrollAppendOnlyExample,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(router),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    CdkScrollableModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [TeachersApiService,HttpClient,HttpClientModule,RoomsApiService,SubjectsApiService,GroupsApiService,ScrollDispatcher],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

new-timetable.component.html :

```
<html>
<body>


<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  appendOnly class="example-viewport"y>
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of arr">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

</body>
</html>
```

new-timetable.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GroupsApiService} from "../../api.services";
import {Groups} from "../../models/groups.model";
import {SubDb} from "../../models/subDb.mobels";




@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-timetable',
  templateUrl: './new-timetable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-timetable.component.css']
})
export class NewTimetableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  arr=['fafsa','fsfafs','gsgad','fafsa','fsfafs','gsgad','fafsa','fsfafs','gsgad','fafsa','fsfafs','gsgad','fafsa','fsfafs','gsgad']
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



}
```